# datalab gcp package vs gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I have been working with python (interacting with BigQuery and Cloud Storage) for several months and more recently have been using Datalab for similar tasks.  I'd appreciate clarification on the difference between the [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/python/) (aka [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python)) package and the [gcp](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/datalab/gcp.html) package that is used in the datalab examples.  Datalab doesn't seem to know about gcloud (trying to import it results in "ImportError: No module named gcloud").

**Update:** Devs on my project have used a variety of python packages over the past year in working with the Google Cloud Platform.  At times, some packages were unstable but improved with subsequent releases.  In some cases the functionality within these packages overlaps and we are looking for expert opinions on which  package(s) to standardize on, and/or recommendations on which packages are best suited for which use-cases.

- Google Cloud Platform [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python)
- Cloud Datalab [gcp](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/datalab/gcp.html)
- [Google API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/)
- [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto)

In particular, we used boto at a time when gcloud-python was unstable, but we assume that if we don't have a need to support access to AWS that we are better off using a Google-specific library rather than boto.  [This page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary?hl=en) which describes/recommends(?) using boto seems actively maintained -- does that mean tht it is a preferred alternative or is the goal just to provide devs with many alternatives?

If this is not an appropriate SO question, I will delete.

Answer (score 1):

gcloud is designed for CLI use. The gcp package is designed specifically for DataLab, and is a more OOP-oriented API, where you will create objects that you can reference later in other cells.

Comment: Thanks, Graham, but I'm not referring to the gcloud CLI but the gcloud python package described [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/).  Or does you answer still hold for that python package?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The second part of my answer still applies though; gcloud is built as a general purpose package without regard to the constraints of Datalab (i.e. a notebook environment) so we are decoupled from gcloud. I can't comment on the various other libraries you mentioned but we want the Datalab gcp.* packages to be the best way to work within Datalab notebooks.

Comment: What's the best way to query BigQuery from within a standalone Python script, not Datalab?